# Algorithms for data symmetrization

Tags: data-transformation, skewness, symmetry

There are statistical methods (e.g. by Box-Cox or Yeo-Johnson, see references below) to automatically bring data vectors as close as possible to symmetry/normality using optimal power transformations.

Sometimes, the mentioned methods fail badly. And here I need your help. Consider for instance the distribution of
$$
  Y := \text{max}(100 - X, 0.0001)
$$
with $X \sim \text{Exponential}(1)$. (Note that $Y := 100 - X$ except for the improbable case that $X \ge 100$ where it is put to a small positive number.) Its values are strictly positive, so Box-Cox-transformation (technically) is possible:

Example in R:

```
set.seed(30)
Y <- pmax(100 - rexp(1000), 0.0001)
bc <- coef(powerTransform(Y))  # 65.12778
yj <- coef(powerTransform(Y, family = "yjPower"))  # 65.78253

par(mfrow = c(3,1))
hist(Y, breaks = "FD")
hist(bcPower(Y, bc), breaks = "FD")
hist(yjPower(Y, yj), breaks = "FD")
```

[image: Histograms of original variable and transformed variables]

The values of $Y$ are raised to a ridiculous power of 65 and the distributions do not look very symmetric.

Of course, by studying the histogram of the untransformed variable $Y$, the problem is easily solved: We can subtract the values from about 100 and then apply Box-Cox to get a nice, symmetric result:

```
bc.eye <- coef(powerTransform(100 - Y))  # 0.2934301
hist(bcPower(100 - Y, bc.eye ), breaks = "FD")
```

[image: Box-Cox + brain]

Now finally my question: Do you know of any algorithms that chooses a linear function followed by a power transform to bring a data vector as close as possible to symmetry?

*References*

Box, G. E. P. and Cox, D. R. (1964) An analysis of transformations. Journal of the Royal Statistical Society, Series B. 26 211-46.

Yeo, I. and Johnson, R. (2000) A new family of power transformations to improve normality or symmetry. Biometrika, 87, 954-959.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the symmetrized Y. For example, do you need an estimate of scale of the symmetrized Y?

Comment: Reasonable question. It is for a toy algorithm that breaks down with heavily skewed variables. You could think of something like PCA to investigate relations between possibly monotonely transformed variables.